# Access Ansible host/group var with Python

Tags: python, ansible

I want to be able to output a value of a `group_var` variable for a host in my ansible inventory from a Python script. I can do this with an Ansible ad hoc command:

```
$ ansible all -i inventory/myInventory.yml -l,3.xx.7xx.175 -m debug -a'var=vertype'

3.xx.xx.175 | SUCCESS => {
    "vertype": "rt"
}
```

But if I try this in Python I can't even find the "vertype" variable.

```
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
import glob
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
...
dl = DataLoader()
inventory_files = glob.glob('inventory/*yml')
im = InventoryManager(loader=dl, sources=inventory_files)
vm = VariableManager(loader=dl, inventory=im)
...
my_host = im.get_host(public_ip_address)
print(vm.get_vars(host=my_host).get('vertype'))
```

But `vm.get_vars(host=my_host)` does not seem to contain the key "vertype", so I get "None" as output. How can I access the value "rt"?

Comment: What is the output of just `print(vm.get_vars(host=my_host))`?

Comment: Is `public_ip_address` the same as `3.xx.7xx.175`? Is `inventory_files` the same as `myInventory`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes it is.